# url.search using pretty permalinks to isolate all pages but the index

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

Is there a way to get url.search to find any page loaded that is NOT the index.

For instance, I want a function to fire on any page load, except the index.

So, for the landing page:

www.foo.com

the function does not fire, but if it loads a following page:

www.foo.com

the function fires. I am using wordpress with pretty permalinks and these pages are dynamic, so I would rather not explicitly name each page. This is what I have so far, not using pretty permalinks, which works because the `page_id` is a constant.

```
var url = location.search;
    if(url.search("page_id") > 0) {
        $('#footer').css('background', '#481d0c');  
        $('.hoverBlock').css('background', '#e4e1d5');
```

I would like the condition to see if the variable contains any letter/number etc, and if so, fire the function.

Something like:

var url = location.search;
        if(url.search("ANY CHARACTER") > 0) {
            $('#footer').css('background', '#481d0c');
            $('.hoverBlock').css('background', '#e4e1d5');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was the search method.

`location.search` is looking for the variables passed through the url.

For instance, if you needed to get the variable from `www.foo.com?p=bar`, then `location.search` would return `bar`

I needed the **actual** url, not the passed variable, so this works:

var url = location.pathname;

```
if(url != "") {
  $('#footer').css('background', '#481d0c');    
  $('.hoverBlock').css('background', '#e4e1d5');
}
```

`location.pathname` will return the url string, not including the domain, or index.

For instance if the url was

```
www.foo.com/bar
```

location.pathname would return `/bar`